# Who is on the Nazi 2 Reichsmark coin?

Tags: nazi-germany, identification, money, numismatics

There is a long haired figure on the 1934 2 Reichsmark coin.

[image]

Who is it?

Comment: In mitigation, the printing is not very obvious -- the "S" looks like a "G." A the "F" in the first name is not obviously one.

Comment: His name is written on the coin.

Comment: This question has been nominated for closure twice. I resist closing a question that has an answer, and as Jeff says, if you are not practiced at reading Fraktur, then the answer may not be obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says on the coin, the [portrait](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces15867.html) is the German poet, philosopher, physician, historian, and playwright [Friedrich Schiller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Schiller).

Schiller's portrait was [replaced](http://coinquest.com/cgi-bin/cq/coins?main_coin=1486) by that of [Paul von Hindenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_von_Hindenburg) from 1935-1939.

Answer (score 6):

Uhm, Friedrich Schiller? It's *written on the coin*.

A famous German poet, philosopher, physician, historian, and playwright (1759 – 1805).